# How to write CAML Query with more than 3 AND Condition

Tags: wss-3.0, caml-query

I have search and see the way how to write CAML Query with 3 AND conditions. However, I am not sure how to write CAML Query with more than 3 AND conditions may be with 4 or 5 AND conditions.

Can any body write for me the CAML Query with 4 or 5 AND conditions. Or any link showing that Query ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Just continue to nest the queries...

```
<And>
    <Eq>... condition...</Eq>
    <And>
        <Eq>... condition...</Eq>
        <And>
            <Eq>... condition...</Eq>
            <And>
                <Eq>... condition...</Eq>
                <Eq>... condition...</Eq>
            </And>
        </And>
    </And>
</And>
```

Comment: Check the Query below, is that is correst ?

Answer (score 2):

just use [CAML Query builder](http://www.u2u.be/res/tools/camlquerybuilder.aspx). This is free tool, just use it's visual interface to create queries of different complexity.

**Update:** The link to u2u builder above is broken now. Currently I use [SPCAMLQueryHelper](http://spcamlqueryhelper.codeplex.com/) from codeplex instead.

Comment: link is broken. Is this still available?

Comment: Currently I use another builder, possibly u2u doesn't support old builder anymore. See my update above.

Comment: the new link no longer works either, the SPCAML one.