# CAML query using OR and AND Condition

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, caml-query

I need to write a CAML query which satisfies the below condition:

> projectstatus == "hold" OR projectstatus == "obsolete "
>   AND
>   ilprilt not equal to "ilp frozen"

When I run this query, am getting records where

`ilprilt not equal to "ilp frozen" and ilprilt not equal to "ilp not frozen"`

I am missing something. Please help with the correct query.
I believe the placement of AND / OR  operator is giving me the error

**projectstatus** --  list column

**ilprilt** -- list column

**projectstatus** values -- *hold* / *obsolete*

**ilprilt**  values --- >  *ilp not frozen* /*ilp  frozen*

Below is my query which isn't giving me correct results:

```
<Query>
    <Where>
        <Or>
            <Eq>
                <FieldRef Name='ProjectStatus' />
                <Value Type='Choice'>Hold</Value>
            </Eq>
            <And>
                <Eq>
                    <FieldRef Name='ProjectStatus' />
                    <Value Type='Choice'>Obsolete</Value>
                </Eq>
                <Neq>
                    <FieldRef Name='ILPRILT' />
                    <Value Type='Choice'>ILP Frozen</Value>
                </Neq>
            </And>
        </Or>
    </Where>
</Query>
```

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zo]

Comment: Can't see your CAML...

Comment: updated just now. what am I missing ?

Answer (score 8):

Placement of `AND` and `OR` in combine query always confuses us.

The only mistake I see in your query is, you have miss placed the `AND` and `OR` elements.

The correct query will be:

```
<Query>
   <Where>
      <And>
         <Or>
            <Eq>
               <FieldRef Name='projectstatus' />
               <Value Type='Choice'>hold</Value>
            </Eq>
            <Eq>
               <FieldRef Name='projectstatus' />
               <Value Type='Choice'>obsolete</Value>
            </Eq>
         </Or>
         <Neq>
            <FieldRef Name='ilprilt' />
            <Value Type='Choice'>ilp frozen</Value>
         </Neq>
      </And>
   </Where>
</Query>
```

This will give you what you want.

You can also go through [How to build nested query in CAML query](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/56816/30145) to get more idea regarding how to build the nested query with `AND` and `OR`.

Answer (score 6):

Try this - I think this will do it. I have not tested it.

```
<Query>
<Where>
<And>
<Or>
<Eq> <FieldRef Name='ProjectStatus' /> <Value Type='Choice'>Hold</Value> </Eq>
<Eq> <FieldRef Name='ProjectStatus' /> <Value Type='Choice'>Obsolete</Value> </Eq>
</Or>
<Neq> <FieldRef Name='ILPRILT' /> <Value Type='Choice'>ILP Frozen</Value> </Neq>
</And>
</Where>
</Query>
```

I find utilities like SPCamlHelper to be useful for testing these queries.

https://spcamlqueryhelper.codeplex.com

Comment: Lemme  try this and revert !

Comment: what if i try with , ilprilt as firts condition within AND and then do a  OR with projectstatus eitehr hold or obsolete ?

Comment: @SaMolPP that will make no difference..