# CAML multiple AND Conditions

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, caml-query, jsom, caml

The CAML query below didn't work for me. Any help?

```
$viewQuery = "<Where><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='PP'/><Value Type='Integer'><UserID Type='Integer'/></Value></Eq><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='Org' /><Value Type='Choice'>Rules</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name='Completed' /><Value Type='Boolean'>0</Value></Eq></And><And><Geq><FieldRef Name='Created' /><Value IncludeTimeValue='FALSE' Type='DateTime'>$FDate</Value></Geq><Leq><FieldRef Name='Created' /><Value IncludeTimeValue='FALSE' Type='DateTime'>$ToDate</Value></Leq></And></And></Where>";
```

The above query works fine if I remove the first condition. when I add the fifth 'And' condition it is throwing error.

PS: I cant install a CAML query builder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try your CAML query in below format:

```
<Where>
    <And>
        <Eq><FieldRef Name='PP'/><Value Type='Integer'><UserID Type='Integer'/></Value></Eq>
        <And>
            <Eq><FieldRef Name='Org' /><Value Type='Choice'>Rules</Value></Eq>
            <And>
                <Eq><FieldRef Name='Completed' /><Value Type='Boolean'>0</Value></Eq>
                <And>
                    <Geq><FieldRef Name='Created' /><Value IncludeTimeValue='FALSE' Type='DateTime'>$FDate</Value></Geq>
                    <Leq><FieldRef Name='Created' /><Value IncludeTimeValue='FALSE' Type='DateTime'>$ToDate</Value></Leq>
                </And>
            </And>
        </And>
    </And>
</Where>
```

**Similar thread**: [How to write CAML Query with more than 3 AND Condition](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/56815/how-to-write-caml-query-with-more-than-3-and-condition)

Comment: That worked. Thanks.